# How to add manual project in AWX docker container

Tags: docker, ansible, containers, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I configured AWX in docker container Followed the stpes given in `https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-ansible-awx-docker-compose-centos-8/`

[image: AWX containers and Projects]

I have created an sample project "test_git_project" from AWX GUI, which is working fine and project directory is created automatically in `/var/lib/awx/projects` in **awx-tasks** container.

And to create **Manual project** I had copied my ansible playbooks to `/var/lib/awx/projects/new_project` directory and tried to create manual project form AWX GUI but it is not displaying the "new_project" which I copied to project directory..

[image]

Could you please guide me how to create manual project in docker awx setup.

Comment: From memory: `/var/lib/awx/projects` should be mounted on a docker volume in both `awx_tasks` and `awx_web` containers. Did you check it is the case and that you can see your manually created folder on both sides? Do you have SE Linux enabled on your system ? (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/projects.html#ug-manual). My 2 cent: since your install seems to work correctly for all the rest and you can successfully clone projects from SCM, I would not mess around manually with my containers.

Comment: @Zeitounator awx now uses disposable Execution Environment pods for running user process, not `awx_task`. Production use is only supported on Kubernetes. There are developer instruction for docker, but they require quite a bit of mucking around to make sure that EE is up and down for each task you run, since it's now handled via kubernetes API in the production builds. As such following outdate unofficial instructions to install the latest awx version as OP seemed to do is not likely to lead to a working installation.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished installing AWX 17.1.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 via AWX Operator, And I stumbled into the same issue.

When you use "Manual" as the source of the project, AWX looks in `/var/lib/awx/projects`. But when you look in the docker-compose file generated by AWX Operator in `~/.awx/awxcompose` no directory on the host server is mounted to this path.

My solution was to add a mount point for both awx_task and awx_web containers.

```
  web:
    image: ansible/awx:17.1.0
    ...
    volumes:
      - /opt/projects:/var/lib/awx/projects
      ...

  task:
    image: ansible/awx:17.1.0
    ...
    volumes:
      - /opt/projects:/var/lib/awx/projects
      ...
```

Don't forget to docker-compose down && docker-compose up for changes to take effect.

You should be able to create directories inside `/opt/projects` and see them as projects inside AWX.